# how to extract the contents of the array?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an application on flutter and I'm a bit stuck at the moment of extracting the contents of firebase classes. How do I extract the contents of the PhoneNumber variable from "user"? I will need the extracted number to send to the server

This is the output of the debugPrint('user: $user'):

```
user: FirebaseUser({uid: hGLEDW6OT5ZMhWra9L4p6bB4Pw92, isAnonymous: false, phoneNumber: +79644054946, providerData: [{uid: hGLEDW6OT5ZMhWra9L4p6bB4Pw92, phoneNumber: +79644054946, providerId: firebase}], providerId: firebase, creationTimestamp: 1557420327980, lastSignInTimestamp: 1558848790729, isEmailVerified: false}
```

```dart
void _signInWithPhoneNumber() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    debugPrint('user: $user');
    setState(() {

      if (user != null) {

           Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/amenities');
      } else {
        _message = 'Вход не выполнен';
      }
    });
}
```

I need to extract PhoneNumber from "user" to send to server in Json

Comment: user.providerData()[0].getPhoneNumber(); // do not hard code the array index. Run necessary checks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can grab the phone number with just `user.phoneNumber`